# Unity and FB Share

Tags: facebook, redirect, unity-game-engine, share

I am trying to use FB.ShareLink provided by Facbook's unity SDK to share my apps on a player's wall.
However, I want the link to redirect to their respective stores depending on the platform the other player is accessing it from.
I already have the apps from different stores linked to my Facebook App Center.
How would I go about doing it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

Comment: AppLinks is designed for this purpose https://developers.facebook.com/products/app-links